# Permissions Issue with AppFusions Google Analytics plugin for Confluence

Tags: google-analytics, confluence

I have recently installed AppFusion's Google Analytics plugin for Confluence, but when I am on a page in a space, I click the 'See who's viewed this page', to which I get a forever loading box stating it's getting information from Google Analytics.

Checking the logs, this is what I get:

```
2015-09-16 20:38:33,423 ERROR [http-nio-8090-exec-9] [plugins.googleanalytics.utils.DataFeedUtils] getGaData  ++ Oh heck:  GoogleJsonResponseException -- 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.",
"reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile."
}
 -- referer: https://confluenceURL | url: /rest/googleanalytics/1.0/content/page/47843376/pageviews/2015-08-16/2015-09-16 | userName: email@email.com
```

See here for information on setting up the plugin: https://www.appfusions.com/display/GANLC/Documentation

Comment: Hi Luca, I'll talk to you on Skype, but it does indeed look like a problem with the Google account you're using. Does the plugin show data elsewhere, or is it just the "Who viewed this?" functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, no website profile had been selected on **Step 4: Select Website Profile** in the plugin configuration screen, so the error logged is *slightly* misleading.

Having created a property in [Google Analytics Administration](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#management/Settings/) and then selected a profile on the plugin configuration screen (below) everything started working again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, David! This solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user that you have authenticated with does not have access to the Google Analytics profile that you have set in your code.

Either give the user you are authenticating with access to read from that account. or Authenticate with an account that does have access.